# Is array shallow copy cheap, regardless of size?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm testing `System.arraycopy`, which does a shallow copy that I assumed is cheap, no matter how many elements I want to copy.

```java
private static int[] randomInts = new int[800];

@Setup
public void setup() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 800; i++) {
        randomInts[i] = rand.nextInt(10000) + 1;
    }
}

// Copy first 20 elements from randomInts
@Benchmark
public int[] testFirst20() {
    final int[] toArray = new int[20];
    System.arraycopy(randomInts, 0, toArray, 0, 20);
    return toArray;
}

// Copy the whole randomInts
@Benchmark
public int[] testFull() {
    final int[] toArray = new int[800];
    System.arraycopy(randomInts, 0, toArray, 0, 800);
    return toArray;
}
```

Results:

```java
Benchmark                     Mode  Cnt       Score      Error   Units
BenchAddToArray.testFirst20  thrpt    5  116484.035 ± 9793.886  ops/ms
BenchAddToArray.testFull     thrpt    5    3348.843 ±  429.225  ops/ms
```

So I guess we should be careful with the performance even if it's shallow copy.
I knew taking a taking a full copy should be more expansive than taking a smaller copy, but didn't expect the difference to be so big.
Could anyone give me some insights as to which part of `System.arraycopy` resulted in the difference between copying arrays of different lengths?

---

Thanks to @Sweeper's comment, I also tested another version where the array initialisation is done in @Setup, so that the benchmark is purely on `arrayCopy`. Got following results:

```java
Benchmark                     Mode  Cnt      Score      Error   Units
BenchAddToArray.testFirst20  thrpt    5  30061.031 ± 4521.763  ops/ms
BenchAddToArray.testFull     thrpt    5   2753.594 ±  117.719  ops/ms
```

So array init does account for a large portion of the difference.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your logic. Why do you think copying 20 things should take the same amount of time as copying 800 things? Even if it is just a shallow copy, you are still doing a thing 20 times vs 800 times.

Comment: I didn't  assume that they'd take the same amount of time, but was expecting less difference than what I got from the benchmark. Reasoning is that: elements in an array is in a contiguous region of memory, (from now on it's all just my assumptions) `arrayCopy` is just taking a slice of that region of the memory according to the size, and then let the new array object point to it. It's like cutting a cake, cutting a small portion of it out vs cutting a big portion shouldn't be too much different? Of course the results said there's something wrong about my understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is No.  The cost of `arraycopy` is proportional to the size of the array that you are copying.

Indeed, your last benchmark demonstrates this to be true.

Frankly, it does not make physical (electrical) sense for copying an N element array to be better than `O(N)`.  That's not how computer memory hardware works.

At a low level (beneath all of the pipelining, caching, etc) copying an array in memory involves RAM reads from one series of locations and RAM writes to another series of locations.  The RAM hardware is only capable of reading / writing 8 or 16 (or something) bytes (lets call the number W) per operation because the memory data bus is only 64 or 128 (or something) bits wide.  Therefore copying N bytes takes N / W memory operations which makes the copy take O(N) clock cycles.